# mrunit test NullPointerException when writing to HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop

So in my reducer I am using MultipleOutputs to write to different files in HDFS
(Full Reducer code below)

I would like to unit test this using mrunit (1.1 is needed to support MultipleOutputs)
and here is my test method

```
@Test
public void testParseValidInput() throws IOException {
    List values = new ArrayList();
    values.add(new Text("{}"));

    reduceDriver.withInput(new Text("aProjectId/2014-04-22T15:42:27.000Z"), values)
                .withMultiOutput(null, new Text("{}"), new Text("aProjectId/2014/04/22/15/42"))
                .runTest();
    }
```

However when I run this test I get an NPE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.(Path.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.(Path.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.getDefaultWorkFile(FileOutputFormat.java:286)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.getRecordWriter(MultipleOutputs.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.write(MultipleOutputs.java:457)
    at com.here.hac.partition.HacDataParReducer.reduce(HacDataParReducer.java:71)
    at com.here.hac.partition.HacDataParReducer.reduce(HacDataParReducer.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.ReduceDriver.run(ReduceDriver.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.TestDriver.runTest(TestDriver.java:625)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.TestDriver.runTest(TestDriver.java:612)
    at com.here.hac.partition.HacDataParReducerTest.test2(HacDataParReducerTest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Here is the Reducer code

```
package com.here.hac.partition;
```

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;

/**
 * Reducer class writes output data to multiple files based on
 * partition rules.
 */
public class HacDataParReducer extends Reducer{
    private MultipleOutputs mos;
    private Long currentTimeInSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    /**
     * Return a file name "path/to/file" based on given (key,value) pair.
     * E.g. for a give key which is in the format of "/",
     *      return file name "/////-"
     * 
     * @param Text key
     * @param Text value
     * @return String File name string.
     */
    private String generateFileName(Text key, Text value){
        String[] parseDate = key.toString().split(":");
        return buildPath(parseDate[0]) + "/" + parseDate[1] +"-"+ currentTimeInSeconds;
    }
    /**
     * Replace '-' and 'T' in a string with '/'. 
     * 
     * E.g. For a input string format as "4spoo7qlgm/2014-04-22T15", return "4spoo7qlgm/2014/04/22/15"
     * 
     * @param String str
     * @return String
     */
    private String buildPath(String str){
        StringBuffer newPath = new StringBuffer();
        for(char c : str.toCharArray()){
            if(c == '-' || c == 'T')
                newPath.append('/');
            else
                newPath.append(c);
        }
        return newPath.toString();
    }
    @Override
    /**
     * Setup data structure needed within the same Reduce Task.
     */
    public void setup(Context context){
        mos = new MultipleOutputs(context);
    }
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        this.currentTimeInSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        for (Text val : values)
        {
            String fileName =  generateFileName(key, val);
            mos.write((Text)null, val, fileName);
        }
    }

```
@Override
/**
 * Clean up any data structure that is initialized in the setup process.
 */
public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    mos.close();
}
```

}

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the complete code for your reducer, so that i can run it and see if i get a similar error

Comment: Added full code to original question - Thanks

Comment: how did you get the 1.1 release for MRUnit ? , the website shows the 1.0.0 is the most latest release http://mrunit.apache.org/

Comment: Using this link http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mrunit-user/201403.mbox/%3CCAFukC=4+qvSTd40DGpaeyriSYrtgy90Km=oQBoutx80yLVEZBw@mail.gmail.com%3E then I found the Jar here https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/orgapachemrunit-1000/org/apache/mrunit/mrunit/1.1.0/